# Unable to login from User account or Guest account (not a duplicate question)

Tags: upgrade, login, lightdm, login-screen, display-manager

I have Dell 3521 laptop without dedicated video card. It came with Ubuntu 12.04 installed. One fine day, it prompted me for an upgrade, which i went for. During upgrade, its battery finished and once I charged it, it wasn't taking me to Login Screen any more. I looked for answers over internet and applying some of those I was able to reach Login Screen. But to my disappointment, now, when I provide password to my user account it flashes some messages and goes back to Login Screen. Flashed messages are all about some FontConfig error and are visible for such a limited time that I can't read them. My Guest account does no Login as well. However, tty commmand line interfaces do work and accept my user account password.
I have researched extensively over internet to find a solution. Some actions that I have done after reading number of blogs are as under:-

- I have removed .Xauthority file.
- I have tried startx and startx-unity which say dispaly is already active.
- I have done chown username:username ..something ..
- I have installed gdm and started it, which could not take me beyond the  purple Ubuntu screen to the Login Screen even.
- I have reverted to lightdm.
- I have run -update -upgrade -reconfigure and what not.

I have some files which I need to recover, otherwise, I would have re-installed new Ubuntu or Windows. Please guide me on following:

- Recovering my system (if possible, give some simple layman instructions).
- If theres no way out, or its too complex for a layman like me, please guide me to locate and retrieve my files (My system has only one logical disk).

This is not a duplicate question as far as recovery is concerned as I have gone through almost all similar questions on askubuntu.com and even other websites.

Comment: I think it's possible to reinstall Ubuntu from an USB stick or DVD **without formatting first**. Then your files in /home should be preserved. But I have never done it myself, so please wait until a more experienced helper can guide you.